# I Want to fetch total product those quantity is less than or equal to zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query (see image) which displays a result as shown in the image below.

Now, I want to `show` those `product` list whose total available `quantity` is less than or `equal to zero`.

I am calculating total available quantity using this formula -

```
(SUM(credit_quantity) - SUM(debit_quantity))
```

Please check the database table structure shown in image:

[image]

Comment: your image is missing??

Comment: Do you have any code to show us ?

Comment: your "following query" is missing too

Comment: I see no "following query", just a formula. I can't see an image either.

Comment: why can't you create a fiddle instead of adding a pic?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `nrk_product` AS `np`  LEFT JOIN `nrk_stock`  AS `ns`  
ON `np`.`id` = `ns`.`product_id`        
GROUP BY `np`.`id` HAVING (SUM(`ns`.`credit_quantity`) - SUM(`ns`.`debit_quantity`)) > 0

Comment: The above query show those  products list whose available quantity is greater than zero, but I want reverse result of this query.

Comment: Please check the fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51802/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
SELECT * FROM nrk_product AS np LEFT JOIN 
nrk_stock AS ns ON np.id = ns.product_id GROUP BY np.id 
HAVING (SUM(ns.credit_quantity) - SUM(ns.debit_quantity)) <= 0
```

Comment: Above Sql Query give me a blank result. Please check fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51802/1

Comment: It doesn't give blank result.